# add padding to textView with drawable background

Tags: android, xml, layout

Is it possible to add padding into TextView with drawable element on its backround? Or do I need to use **Draw 9-patch** ?

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_background"
    android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
/>
```

This padding settings does not work. For 3-4 digits the background is displayed correctly but when it should adjust (for 5/6 digits) it stays the same.

UPDATE - add image
[image]

Comment: `android:drawablePadding` will create a padding gap between the text and the drawable

Comment: @Mohit Kacha Unfortunatly this parameter doesnt work

Comment: are you using relativelayout r linearlayout?

Comment: @Expiredmind  It means you are adding Wrong parameter in arguments .
Ex - `jsonObject.getString(USER_ID)' here User_Id may wrong.

Comment: please give full xml code

Comment: @Akash pasupathi FrameLayout in RelativeLayout in LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

If You are adding drawable as background then drawablePadding doesn't works.

You just have to give proper padding to you TextView, so that it can handle most of your usecases.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_bankid_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout_user_detail"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_huge"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_small"
    android:text="@string/login_bankid"
    android:textColor="@color/app_background_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal" />
```

Never give static height or width to your layouts as you have used in height. It will create problem in different screens and you will face text cutoff.

Comment: I dont see  the diffrences in your example. Setting padding for textview does not have any influence into  backround drawable size.

Comment: is your background drawable xml or some image? Whatever your background drawable is, your layout resizes to text size plus padding you give. And your background drawable will cover whole layout size.

Comment: So i need to add my text_background.png into selector XML without adding any parameters and then set background in TextView as xml file and then the padding will trigger correcly?

Comment: can you post text_background.png image?

Comment: your background image already has some padding. thats why bigger text overflowing out of that.